# mu4e - A "Folder mode" buffer?

Tags: mu4e

I am in the process of switching from Wanderlust to mu4e. I have multiple IMAP accounts and folders, and I used the "contexts" mechanism to configure each of them in their own specific ways. So far, everything is working fine.

However, there is one feature of Wanderlust that I miss within mu4e: a "Folder mode" buffer. This is a buffer which contains a list of summary information for each active IMAP folder that I am dealing with. I can navigate from one folder to the next simply by selecting its line within this Folder mode buffer.

The Folder mode buffer looks like the following example:

```
    - Email     :0/0/3745
        work        :0/0/190
        home        :0/0/803
        girlfriend  :0/0/2128
        misc        :0/0/624
```

The numbers represent new, unread, and total messages.

Has anyone constructed anything similar that works under mu4e? It doesn't have to be exactly the same. Instead of folders, it could be a list of contexts.

The main thing I'm looking for is a list of folders or contexts that I can choose from, with some message counts.

Anyway, at some point, I'm going to try to create such a thing for mu4e. But if something like this already exists, I don't want to go through the effort of reinventing the wheel.

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen "mu4e-maildirs-extension" (https://github.com/agpchil/mu4e-maildirs-extension)?

This provides something similar to your request, but it does require a specific account/folder structure.

When installed it adds a folder/count hierarchy below the normal stuff on the mu4e "welcome" screen (from M-x mu4e).

For example, for my configuration I get the following (truncated/obfuscated) content:

```
- my@example.com (46022/185227)
  | Archives-2013 (0/0)
  | Drafts (0/134)
  | INBOX (4/41)
  | Infected (9/268)
  - Junk (137/12995)
  | Junk E-mail (0/0)
  | Junk-Train-Ham (0/0)
  | Junk-Train-Spam (0/21)
  - Lists (0/0)
  - Lists-Emacs (0/0)
  | Lists-Emacs-Org-mode (1201/1201)
  | Lists-Mailpile (0/0)
  | Lists-Mu (45/45)
  | Lists-Notmuch (1876/1876)
  | Lists-Obnam (12/12)
  | Lists-Slim-Beta (4145/5414)
  | Lists-Slim-Checkins (70/89)
  | Lists-Slim-Developers (1570/2170)
  | Lists-Slim-Discuss (8990/15504)
  | Lists-Slim-Jive (19/19)
  | Lists-Slim-Plugins (18727/24477)
  | Lists-Slim-Unix (8378/14141)
  | Lists-Squeeze-Dev (0/2)
  :
  :
```

It's available on MELPA.